# jquery change() not working within hidden div

Tags: jquery, forms, reload

I've been wondering and can't find a solution why the operation $("#locationid3").change (line 85) is not working even though it's the same as 
$("#locationid").change and $("#locationid2").change (the lines above it). The main difference is :
- #locationid and #locationid2 is placed directly within the html-form and is always visible
- #locationid3 is placed in a hidden div outside the html-form and will only be shown if "prod2" in product-dropdown is selected

the reason for creating a hidden div outside the form is so the fieldsets inside the form can be reloaded by changing the product-dropdown. By changing the product, all fieldset will be hidden with method "hideFieldsets()" and the corresponding fieldset (using account, product, data-id and data-position) will be shown with method "showFieldset()".

I've put the code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/330jny9z)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#accountid").change(function() {
            var $dropdown = $(this);
            var accounts = {
               "id_1":{"products":[{"id":"1","val":"prod1"},{"id":"2","val":"prod2"}],"locations":[{"id":"4","val":"loc1"},{"id":"1","val":"loc2"}],}

               };


            var key = $dropdown.val();
            var products = {};
            var locations = {};
            var locations2 = {};
            var locations3 = {};
            switch(key) {
                case 'id_1' :products = accounts.id_1.products;locations = accounts.id_1.locations;locations2 = locations;locations3 = locations;break;


            }


            var $productid = $("#productid");
            $productid.empty();
            $.each(products, function(index, value) {
            var option = $('<option></option>').val(value.id).text(value.val);
            $productid.append(option);

            });

            $('#productid').val();
            $productid.trigger("change");

            var $locationid = $("#locationid");
            $locationid.empty();
            $.each(locations, function(index, value) {
            var option = $('<option></option>').val(value.id).text(value.val);
            $locationid.append(option);

            });


            var $locationid2 = $("#locationid2");
            $locationid2.empty();
            $.each(locations2, function(index, value) {
            var option = $('<option></option>').val(value.id).text(value.val);
            $locationid2.append(option);

            });


            var $locationid3 = $("#locationid3");
            $locationid3.empty();
            $.each(locations3, function(index, value) {
            var option = $('<option></option>').val(value.id).text(value.val);
            $locationid3.append(option);

            });


        });



    $("#productid").change(function() {
        var possibleFieldsets = {

        "id_1_1" : ["id_1_1__ test ","id_1_1__ test2 "],
        "id_1_2" : ["id_1_2__ test ","id_1_2__ test2 "],
        };

        hideFieldsets();
        var selectedAccProd = $("#accountid option:selected").val()+"_"+$("#productid option:selected").val();
        showFieldsets(possibleFieldsets[selectedAccProd]);

    });

        $("#locationid").change(function() {
            readLocationData(this.value);
        });

        $("#locationid2").change(function() {
            readLocationData(this.value);
        });

        $("#locationid3").change(function() {
            readLocationData(this.value);
        });

        var allFieldset = {};
        $('#allFieldsets').children().each(function(index,fieldsetElement){
            var $fieldsetElement = $(fieldsetElement);
            allFieldset[$fieldsetElement.attr("data-id")] = $fieldsetElement;
        });
        $('#allFieldsets').remove();


        function hideFieldsets(){

            for(var key in allFieldset){
                var $div = $('fieldset[data-id="'+key+'"]').parent();
                if($div.children().length > 0){
                    allFieldset[key] = $div.children();
                    $div.empty();
                }
                $div.hide();
            }
        }

        function showFieldsets(fieldsetArray){
            $.each(fieldsetArray, function(index, element){
                var $div = $('div[data-position="'+element.split('__')[1]+'"]');
                $div.append(allFieldset[element]);
                $div.show();

            });

        } 
         function readOrderData(orderId){
            window.alert("reading data");
        }



        function readLocationData(locationId){
            window.alert("location changed");
        }

        $("#accountid").trigger("change");
      });

      $isUnread = false;
```

I would really appreciate any lead / advice on how to make #locationsid3 change() works. Thanx!

Comment: use `$("#locationid3").on("change",function() {
            readLocationData(this.value);
        });` OR  `$("document").on("change", "#locationid3",function() {
            readLocationData(this.value);`
        });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not simply doing show/hide on the #location3 select box. You are removing the html from the page and appending it again when prod2 is selected. You need to use .on method of jquery. Because it will fire the events bind with html loaded after dom creation.

```
$('body').on('change','#locationid3',function(){
   readLocationData(this.value);
});
```

Check this demo: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tqojx8ox/)

Comment: Thank you so much! Glad to know there's a simple solution to the problem :)

Comment: @Alex, You can up vote the answers so the others can also use this solution.

Comment: I tried, but it's not possible because I dont have 15+ reputation yet :(

Answer (score 1):

Because your `#locationid3` is dynamically changed, the normal selection won't work. You need to use the following format:

```
$("#parent-element").on("change", "#find-this-element", function(){})
```

The `#parent-element` has to be static, so if you only has a static `body`, you can do `$("body").on("change", "#find-this-element", function(){})`. However, you should use the closest static element to improve performance.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Just like suiggested above, the $(document).on("change", "#locationid3", function() solves the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You should delegate the `change` event to the parent element. This is needed since when the event is bound on `document.ready`, dropdown 3 would be hidden in DOM and is shown only later.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#accountid").change(function() {
    var $dropdown = $(this);
    var accounts = {
      "id_1": {
        "products": [{
          "id": "1",
          "val": "prod1"
        }, {
          "id": "2",
          "val": "prod2"
        }],
        "locations": [{
          "id": "4",
          "val": "loc1"
        }, {
          "id": "1",
          "val": "loc2"
        }],
      }

    };


    var key = $dropdown.val();
    var products = {};
    var locations = {};
    var locations2 = {};
    var locations3 = {};
    switch (key) {
      case 'id_1':
        products = accounts.id_1.products;
        locations = accounts.id_1.locations;
        locations2 = locations;
        locations3 = locations;
        break;


    }


    var $productid = $("#productid");
    $productid.empty();
    $.each(products, function(index, value) {
      var option = $('<option></option>').val(value.id).text(value.val);
      $productid.append(option);

    });

    $('#productid').val();
    $productid.trigger("change");

    var $locationid = $("#locationid");
    $locationid.empty();
    $.each(locations, function(index, value) {
      var option = $('<option></option>').val(value.id).text(value.val);
      $locationid.append(option);

    });


    var $locationid2 = $("#locationid2");
    $locationid2.empty();
    $.each(locations2, function(index, value) {
      var option = $('<option></option>').val(value.id).text(value.val);
      $locationid2.append(option);

    });


    var $locationid3 = $("#locationid3");
    $locationid3.empty();
    $.each(locations3, function(index, value) {
      var option = $('<option></option>').val(value.id).text(value.val);
      $locationid3.append(option);

    });


  });



  $("#productid").change(function() {
    var possibleFieldsets = {

      "id_1_1": ["id_1_1__ test ", "id_1_1__ test2 "],
      "id_1_2": ["id_1_2__ test ", "id_1_2__ test2 "],
    };

    hideFieldsets();
    var selectedAccProd = $("#accountid option:selected").val() + "_" + $("#productid option:selected").val();
    showFieldsets(possibleFieldsets[selectedAccProd]);

  });

  $("#locationid").change(function() {

    readLocationData(this.value);
  });

  $("#locationid2").change(function() {

    readLocationData(this.value);
  });

  $(document).on("change", "#locationid3", function() {
    console.log("here");
    readLocationData(this.value);
  });

  var allFieldset = {};
  $('#allFieldsets').children().each(function(index, fieldsetElement) {
    var $fieldsetElement = $(fieldsetElement);
    allFieldset[$fieldsetElement.attr("data-id")] = $fieldsetElement;
  });
  $('#allFieldsets').remove();


  function hideFieldsets() {

    for (var key in allFieldset) {
      var $div = $('fieldset[data-id="' + key + '"]').parent();
      if ($div.children().length > 0) {
        allFieldset[key] = $div.children();
        $div.empty();
      }
      $div.hide();
    }
  }

  function showFieldsets(fieldsetArray) {
    $.each(fieldsetArray, function(index, element) {
      var $div = $('div[data-position="' + element.split('__')[1] + '"]');
      $div.append(allFieldset[element]);
      $div.show();

    });

  }

  function readOrderData(orderId) {
    window.alert("reading data");
  }



  function readLocationData(locationId) {
    window.alert("location changed");
  }

  $("#accountid").trigger("change");
});

$isUnread = false;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" id="orderForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <fieldset data-id="admin">
    <legend>Admin</legend>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="accountid">Kunde:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select id="accountid" name="accountid">
            <option value="id_1">acc1</option>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
          <label for="productid">Produkt:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select id="productid" name="productid">
            <option value="1">prod1</option>
            <option value="2">prod2</option>
          </select>
        </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="locationid">Standort:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select id="locationid" name="locationid">
            <option value="4">loc1</option>
            <option value="1">loc2</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="locationid2">Standort2:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select id="locationid2" name="locationid2">
            <option value="4">loc1</option>
            <option value="1">loc2</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>

      </tr>
    </table>
  </fieldset>
  <div data-position=" test "></div>
  <div data-position=" test2 "></div>


  <hr>
</form>
<div style="display:none; width:0px; height:0px; position:absolute; top:-1px; left:-1px" id="allFieldsets">
  <fieldset data-id="id_1_1__ test " data-position=" test ">
    <legend>test</legend>
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="registrationnumber">test111</label>
          </td>

        </tr>

      </table>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset data-id="id_1_1__ test2 " data-position=" test2 ">
    <legend>test2</legend>
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="appointmentdate">test112</label>
          </td>

        </tr>

      </table>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset data-id="id_1_2__ test " data-position=" test ">
    <legend>test</legend>
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="registrationnumber">test121</label>
          </td>

        </tr>

      </table>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset data-id="id_1_2__ test2 " data-position=" test2 ">
    <legend>test2</legend>
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="appointmentdate">test122</label>
          </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="locationid3">Standort3:</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select id="locationid3" name="locationid3">
              <option value="4">loc1</option>
              <option value="1">loc2</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>

        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </fieldset>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! Just like suiggested above, the $(document).on("change", "#locationid3", function() solves the problem :)